# Comparing character arrays is not working

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I have found a problem while trying to use "character arrays" in an `if` condition. It should be `true` with my input, but it is not.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[20];
    cin.get(a,15, '\n');       // for input
    cout << a << endl;         // output
    if (a == "hello world") {  // checking if condition
       cout << "how are you?" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need [`strcmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) ( include the header `<cstring>` ) to check equality of character arrays.

Try

```
    if( !strcmp(a,"hello world"))
```

BTW, since you are on c++, it's better to use `std::string`, so you can easily do

```
std::string a;
getline( std::cin , a );
if(a=="hello world") //checking if condition
{
  std::cout<<"how are you";
}
```

Comment: Isn't that `if (strcmp(a,"hello world") == 0)` to get the same?

Comment: @nielsen , you didn't check it clearly, look closely and you will find a `!` there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , I know that char arrays are error prone, that's why I also recommended `std::string`

Comment: @ShrawanBk, a `cin` will skip whitespaces like space, newline, etc, so anything beyond the space is not stored if you use a simple `cin`. Use `cin.getline( a,100)` instead. And also, **please do not post code in comments**.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Code blurp in comments  :C=

Comment: The first example works for me. The space is treated as a space. And it is read by `cin.get`without any problems.

Comment: Stop dumping senseless code please. Your posts are very hard to read. Can't you see that?

Comment: @ArunA.S sir tq :)
I just think I got it.

Answer (score 3):

**You should be using `std::string`, not some `char[]`.**

Then the equality will work as you expect.

This `char[20]`, `strcmp` nonsense is archaic and error-prone. There is no place for it here.

Comment: Is there any good reason why so many people still use `char[]` instead of `std::string` in c++?